# Parameterized query in C# OleDb. Incomplete query issue

Tags: c#, oledb, ms-access-2003, parameterized-query

I'm having trouble with table names used as parameters in OleDb. As I looked through forums with similar questions, I got that it's actually impossible to use parameters in that fashion. But there wasn't given any solution to this problem. Of course, I can use actual table names, but there are lots of them, so it would be easier to process necessary tables separately. And I tried to use just string concatenation using dynamic sql which leads to SQL injection problems. So, here's my code

```
foreach (String Data in tablelist)
        {
            if (Data == "Harvard")
            {
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@tablename", OleDbType.Char);
               cmd.Parameters["@tablename"].Value = Data;
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@University", Data);
               cmd.CommandText = "insert into @tablename ([Firstname],[Lastname]) values (?,?)";
            }
        }
```

Given that I cannot use parameter in INSERT INTO statement which command I should use not having troubled Command. How can this difficulty be overcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you get the tablenames? If you provide a whitelist of names where the user can choose without any possibility of editing them then you are pretty safe from Sql Injection based on malicious user input. So you can use string concatenation in this context

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers in sql. even if you could, your code would cause an exception for any table that does not contain the FirstName and LastName columns. As a matter of fact, the code in your question doesn't make sense at all - You have the table name hard coded, yet you try to use it with a named parameter (though OleDb does not support named parameters), And you are inserting the same data to both parameters.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. What do you mean by user-editing names possibility. As I understand, the only way to deal with it is to use string concatenation using whitelist of names. In my case, users just select table name from the list presented (actually from combobox) and code processes it.  @Steve

Comment: That's what I mean for whitelist of tablenames. User cannot type its text and thus cannot write malicious strings to wreak havoc with your db. In this context you can use string concatenations. Of course having this flexibility in the table name is not enough to write correct code because you need to know the names of the fields of that particular table that you want to insert records. This is not a normal pattern for LOB applications. So I can't really suggest you anything than don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to concatenate the SQL and the table name, like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into " + Data + " ([Firstname],[Lastname]) values (?,?)";
```